# How to reference a variable from an outer loop in an inner loop in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, sql-insert

I am trying to reference a value from a FOR LOOP that I've created with a SELECT statement, as a parameter in an INSERT statement within that FOR LOOP.

More specifically, I am trying to use that parameter to assemble a db_link to pull data from.

This block of code works if I hard-code a db_link in it, as such:

```
BEGIN
    FOR db IN
        (
        SELECT database_sid FROM STATS.DB_INFO
        WHERE ENV='P'
        )
    LOOP 
        INSERT INTO STATS.CPU_STATS
        SELECT db.database_sid, AVG_CPU_UTILIZATION
        FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@ORCL.world;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

However, I need to collect data from several other databases (yes, the db_links already exist for all of them), so hard-coding a single db_link here (ORCL.world) doesn't work for me. I need to loop thru a dynamically created list.

So, I need something more like this, but it fails:

```
BEGIN
    FOR db IN
        (
        SELECT database_sid FROM STATS.DB_INFO
        WHERE ENV='P'
        )
    LOOP 
        INSERT INTO STATS.CPU_STATS
        SELECT db.database_sid, AVG_CPU_UTILIZATION
        FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@db.database_sid.world;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Note:** STATS is a schema in the local DB that I am collecting this info into. I need to pull data dynamically from several other databases into this local DB.

---

I've tried different variations on that FROM clause referencing the db_link, but so far all of them have failed.

`FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@db.target_sid`

`FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@db.target_sid.world`

`FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@db.target_sid||'.world'`

...and various other combinations of the above.

I've also tried constructing the string as a variable.

```
v_dblink := db.TARGET_SID||'.world';
...
FROM GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@v_dblink
```

But that fails as well.

This seems like it should be simple, like I just need an escape character or something, but nothing I've attempted so far has executed successfully.

Most of the examples I've seen on StackOverflow just dump a dbms_ouput of variables from that first loop to the screen in that inner loop. Which works fine, but is not what I'm going for here. I need to actively **use** those variables to construct the inner loop statement.

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic sql to build the INSERT statement?

Comment: Database link is part of [**object name**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) (identifier). Identifiers cannot be replaced by any variable, because they are part of semantics check, whis is performed before any variable's data is passed to plan executor. You have to build dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for dynamic SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR db IN (
    SELECT database_sid
    FROM   STATS.DB_INFO
    WHERE  ENV='P'
  )
  LOOP 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'INSERT INTO STATS.CPU_STATS
       SELECT :1, AVG_CPU_UTILIZATION
       FROM   GV$RSRCMGRMETRIC_HISTORY@' || db.database_sid || '.world'
      USING db.database_sid;
  END LOOP;
END; 
/
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, that did the trick!  Turns out I was overthinking things.